# TensorFlow program sometimes works, sometimes throws different errors related to reshape nodes at different points in training using same random seed

Tags: tensorflow

I'm having difficulty with a  particularly spooky-looking TensorFlow issue. (TensorFlow 1.4.1 and Python 2.7)

## Errors

I'm seeing a couple different errors when running the same program. Here is an example of one:

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
2018-03-15 18:52:25.377745: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
2018-03-15 18:52:25.378256: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
2018-03-15 18:52:25.378753: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
2018-03-15 18:52:25.379193: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
2018-03-15 18:52:25.379692: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
2018-03-15 18:52:25.380208: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
2018-03-15 18:52:25.380709: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
2018-03-15 18:52:25.381166: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
2018-03-15 18:52:25.381654: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
2018-03-15 18:52:25.382138: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
2018-03-15 18:52:25.382601: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
2018-03-15 18:52:25.383111: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
2018-03-15 18:52:25.383601: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
2018-03-15 18:52:25.384107: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
2018-03-15 18:52:25.384551: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
2018-03-15 18:52:25.384792: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
2018/03/15 18:52:25 ERROR|--|Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "experiment_runner.py", line 140, in experimentset
    results = e.run()
  File "experiment_runner.py", line 69, in run
    results = run_fn()
  File "experiment_runner.py", line 100, in traintest
    return tt.run(self.exp_specs, self.data, model)
  File "/s/chopin/a/grad/jonbyrd/protqa/protqa/experiment/train_test.py", line 149, in run
    return self._fit_model(exp_specs, data, model)
  File "/s/chopin/a/grad/jonbyrd/protqa/protqa/experiment/train_test.py", line 56, in _fit_model
    self.train_proteins_epoch(data["train"], model, exp_specs["args"]["minibatch_size"])
  File "/s/chopin/a/grad/jonbyrd/protqa/protqa/experiment/train_test.py", line 186, in train_proteins_epoch
    model.train(minibatch)
  File "/s/chopin/a/grad/jonbyrd/protqa/protqa/modeling/models/tf_model.py", line 169, in train
    results = self._train(data, options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata, **kwargs)
  File "/s/chopin/a/grad/jonbyrd/protqa/protqa/modeling/models/tf_model.py", line 113, in _train
    results = self.run_graph([self.train_op, self.loss], data, "train", **kwargs)
  File "/s/chopin/a/grad/jonbyrd/protqa/protqa/modeling/models/protnet.py", line 135, in run_graph
    return self.sess.run(outputs, feed_dict=feed_dict, options=options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1120, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1317, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1336, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]

Caused by op u'optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape', defined at:
  File "experiment_runner.py", line 332, in <module>
    main()
  File "experiment_runner.py", line 328, in main
    e.run()
  File "experiment_runner.py", line 69, in run
    results = run_fn()
  File "experiment_runner.py", line 140, in experimentset
    results = e.run()
  File "experiment_runner.py", line 69, in run
    results = run_fn()
  File "experiment_runner.py", line 99, in traintest
    model = tt.build_model(self.exp_specs, self.data)
  File "/s/chopin/a/grad/jonbyrd/protqa/protqa/experiment/train_test.py", line 141, in build_model
    model = eval(hparams["name"] + "(exp_specs, data['train'])")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/s/chopin/a/grad/jonbyrd/protqa/protqa/modeling/models/protnet.py", line 110, in __init__
    self.setup_loss()
  File "/s/chopin/a/grad/jonbyrd/protqa/protqa/modeling/models/tf_model.py", line 90, in setup_loss
    self.train_op = self.hparams["optimizer"](self.loss, **self.hparams["optimizer_args"])
  File "/s/chopin/a/grad/jonbyrd/protqa/protqa/modeling/optimizers.py", line 9, in tf_sgd
    return tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 343, in minimize
    grad_loss=grad_loss)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 414, in compute_gradients
    colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 581, in gradients
    grad_scope, op, func_call, lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 353, in _MaybeCompile
    return grad_fn()  # Exit early
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 581, in <lambda>
    grad_scope, op, func_call, lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_grad.py", line 373, in _GatherGrad
    values = array_ops.reshape(grad, values_shape)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3938, in reshape
    "Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

...which was originally created as op u'energy_2/map/while/Gather', defined at:
  File "experiment_runner.py", line 332, in <module>
    main()
[elided 6 identical lines from previous traceback]
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/s/chopin/a/grad/jonbyrd/protqa/protqa/modeling/models/protnet.py", line 77, in __init__
    dtype=tf.float32, parallel_iterations=32)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/functional_ops.py", line 389, in map_fn
    swap_memory=swap_memory)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2816, in while_loop
    result = loop_context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2640, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2590, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/functional_ops.py", line 379, in compute
    packed_fn_values = fn(packed_values)
  File "/s/chopin/a/grad/jonbyrd/protqa/protqa/modeling/models/protnet.py", line 75, in <lambda>
    ], None, in_dims=nv, in_dists=self.in_dists, **args)[0],
  File "/s/chopin/a/grad/jonbyrd/protqa/protqa/modeling/models/nn_components.py", line 447, in energy
    return tf.reshape(tf.reduce_mean(tf.einsum('abi,abj->abij', (tf.expand_dims(verts, axis=1) * tf.gather(verts, hood_indices)), dists), axis=[0,1]), [in_dims*in_dists]), None
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 2486, in gather
    params, indices, validate_indices=validate_indices, name=name)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1834, in gather
    validate_indices=validate_indices, name=name)
  File "/s/jawar/j/nobackup/protein_learning/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_2/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
```

However, I'm getting several different errors. For this node in my graph:

```
[[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_1/map/while/Gather_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_1/map/while/mul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, optimizer/gradients/energy_1/map/while/Gather_grad/concat)]]
```

Here are some of the errors I've seen:

```
Size 1 must be non-negative, not -1231271574
Size 1 must be non-negative, not -1225669337
Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 0
Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 1715491170492
Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 1693172050944
Input to reshape is a tensor with 122496 values, but the requested shape has 1706639062128
```

For this node in my graph:

```
[[Node: optimizer/gradients/energy_1/map/while/Mean_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/energy_1/map/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3_grad/tuple/control_dependency, optimizer/gradients/energy_1/map/while/Mean_grad/DynamicStitch/_203)]]
```

I've seen these errors for example:

```
Size 0 must be non-negative, not -1237175937
Input to reshape is a tensor with 512 values, but the requested shape has 0
```

I also had a "Nan in summary histogram" error, but I'm going to assume that was due to model divergence.

I don't understand why I'm getting these reshape-related errors at runtime, halfway through the training process. I also don't understand why the values in these errors change each run.

## Circumstances

When running the same program with the same hyperparameters on the same data with the same numpy and tensorflow random seeds, the program will sometimes run without issues, but usually throw one of these errors at different points in the training process. Sometimes this happens at the very first epoch, sometimes after many training epoch (even after 40+ epochs, shortly before the training finishes).

The strange thing is that this seems to be very dependent on the number of latent features/convolution filters in the layer before the one that throws the error. Smaller numbers of filters like 16, 32, 64, and 128 will almost always get errors related to the first computation graph node I mentioned, while a 512 filters will mostly get errors related to the second node. These hyperparameter numbers failed 7-10/10 runs.

However, running the program with that number of filters being either 1 or 1024 was successful 10/10 runs, which confuses me.

## Program

The program is part of a research framework for deep learning on protein structures. The part that is giving me errors is part of a graph convolutional/message-passing network that downsamples a variable-size/shape graph to a single latent representation. The number of filters in the previous section corresponds to the number of latent features per node in the graph.

Here is the downsampling method:

```
def energy(input, _, in_dims, in_dists, **kwargs):
    '''Params:
        input: a tuple representing a single graph containing:
            a 2d tensor of vertex representations(vertices x features)
            a 3d tensor of distance metrics between nodes (vertices x neighbors x distances)
            a 2d tensor containing indices of the neighbors of each vertex in the first tensor(vertices x neighbor indices)
        in_dims: number of incoming features for each vertex
        in_dists: number of distance metrics

    Returns: a 1d tensor of size [in_dims*in_dists] which is the sum over all pairs of neighboring vertices of
    (the outer product of (the elementwise product of the two vertices) and the distances).
    '''
    verts, dists, hood_indices = input
    return tf.reshape(tf.reduce_mean(tf.einsum('abi,abj->abij', (tf.expand_dims(verts, axis=1) * tf.gather(verts, hood_indices)), dists), axis=[0,1]), [in_dims*in_dists]), None
```

Here is the map_fn where that method is called, where layer_fn is the above method:

```
              # downsample each graph using layer_fn
                input = tf.map_fn(
                    lambda ind, data=input[0], merge_fn=layer_fn, nv=input[0].get_shape().as_list()[-1], args=args: merge_fn(
                        [tf.slice(data, [tf.squeeze(tf.slice(ind, [0], [1])), 0],
                                 [tf.squeeze(tf.slice(ind, [1], [1])), nv], name="merge_vertex_slice"),
                         tf.slice(self.distances, [tf.squeeze(tf.slice(ind, [0], [1])), 0, 0],
                                  [tf.squeeze(tf.slice(ind, [1], [1])), self.in_nhood_size, self.in_dists], name="merge_distance_slice"),
                         tf.slice(tf.squeeze(self.in_hood_indices), [tf.squeeze(tf.slice(ind, [0], [1])), 0],
                                  [tf.squeeze(tf.slice(ind, [1], [1])), self.in_nhood_size], name="merge_index_slice"),
                         ], None, in_dims=nv, in_dists=self.in_dists, **args)[0],
                    tf.stack([tf.cumsum(self.graph_orders, exclusive=True), self.graph_orders], axis=-1),
                    dtype=tf.float32, parallel_iterations=32)
```

Stack Overflow will not allow me to post the class that builds the computation graph as it brings my post over the character limit.

The program runs without errors when using a top_k method to downsample the graph.

---

### Confusion

I don't understand why I would get these reshape errors after successful training epochs, or why the number of filters is affecting the issue in such a way. I also don't understand why I'm getting different values in the reshape errors each time. The tensor dimensions should all be fixed except for the number of examples in a minibatch (which I handle via the map_fn) and the number of vertices in each example graph.

I'm having considerable difficulty figuring this out and would be very grateful for outside input. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue ended up being that I was passing indices to tf.gather() that were larger than the size of the tensor I was trying to gather from (the hood_indices within the energy function). I'm not exactly sure how that led to the errors I was seeing, but it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Size 0 must be non-negative, not -1610612736 [Op:Reshape]"

It turns out to be related to tf.repeat. Basically, the following simple code will get you an OOM error:

```
a = tf.range(5000000)
b = tf.concat([tf.zeros(5000000-1, dtype=tf.int32),tf.constant([5000000], dtype=tf.int32)], axis=0)
c = tf.repeat(a,b)
```

The solution is to tune args of tf.repeat, e.g. make `input` smaller (discard useless values), remove zeros from `repeats`

For more details: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/46648#issuecomment-876168035